# The meaning of 'season' here

Tags: word-meaning

From Mariel of Redwall by Brian Jacques

> Sister Sage chuckled and shook her head. 'Cowslips! Look at those two
>   young uns, would you! It makes you feel good to be alive on a
>   summertide.' With that, she hopped off after them, capering madly
>   despite her **long seasons**.

What does the '**season**' mean here?

Comment: Despite her advanced age or despite a long period of illness.  This is very old-fashioned rural speech.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seasons "3. **year** : a boy of seven seasons"